# What makes a bond non-polarisable?

Tags: bond, polarity

Many chemical bonds are known to be polarisable. Similarly, many ions are also known to be polarisable. Examples include the carbon-iodine bond and the carbonate ion. Recently, I have read that the carbon-fluorine bond is, in fact, non-polarisable. Reasons for this include the high electronegativity of fluorine and the small sizes of the carbon and fluorine atoms.

- Do other non-polarisable bonds exist?
- What factors would contribute to a chemical bond being non-polarisable?

Comment: Polarizability is a property of compounds. Bonds contribute to it relatively little.